# For what values of $a,b,c$ will $ax^2+bx+c \geq 0$ hold $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If I let $y=ax^2+bx+c, (a\neq 0)$ then extremum of $y$ is attained at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$.

Then $\large\frac{\mathrm {d^2}y}{\mathrm {d}x^2}\big|_{(x=-\frac{b}{2a})}=2a$ which is positive or negative accordingly as $a>0$ or $a<0$ respectively. For $a>0$ local minimum of $y$ is obtained and the minimum value is $y(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$. For $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ the inequality $y\geq 0$ must also hold, whence $\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\geq 0$.

For $a>0$, $b^2\leq 4ac$ and for $a<0$, $b^2\geq 4ac$ which should be the required condition. Is this a correct conclusion?

Again, can I solve $y\geq 0$ to get $x\geq \frac{-b\pm {\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}}{2a}$? But then for $x$ to be real $b^2-4ac\geq 0$ must hold. So I am a little confused.

Comment: In order to have at most one real solution you need $b^2-4ac\le 0\implies b^2\le 4ac$. Now, if $a<0$ then $\displaystyle y_{max}=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\le 0$, hence it is not satisfies what you are asking for (In this case, $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:\ ax^2+bx+c\le 0$), thus you want $b^2\le 4ac\wedge a>0$.

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate @Galc 127 ?

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wanted to comment, but it became too long and I think that this post will be more helpful.

We would like to find conditions such that $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:\ ax^2+bx+c\ge 0,\quad a\ne0$.

As we know the number of roots of the function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is $0,1\text{ or }2$.

Here are examples for three functions (one for each option):
$\hspace{156pt}$[image]

Now, we want the function to be above $x$ axis or touching it, but not going below it. If there are two real solutions, the function has to go from negative values to positive values and vice verse, thus our first condition is that the function has no more than single root.

As we know, roots of function are $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$thus, it will have at most single solution when $b^2-4ac\le 0$ (single root when $b^2-4ac=0$, no real roots when $b^2-4ac<0$).

Now, we need to check whether the function is above the axis or below it. The function has an extreme point at $\displaystyle \left(-\frac{b}{2a},\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\right)$. We know that $b^2-4ac\le 0$, thus the sign of $y$ coordinate depends on the sign of $a$. If $a>0$ then the point is a minima and then $y_{min}\ge 0$, thus $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:\ f(x)\ge 0$. If $a<0$ then the point is a maxima and then $y_{max}\le 0$, thus $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:\ f(x)\le 0$.

Conclusions:

1. If $b^2-4ac>0$, then the function has two real roots, hence gets positive and negative values.
2. If $b^2-4ac\le 0 \wedge a>0$, then $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:\ f(x)\ge 0$.
3. If $b^2-4ac\le 0 \wedge a<0$, then $\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:\ f(x)\le 0$.

Comment: Isn't the extrema point $\left (\frac{-b}{2a},\frac{-D}{4a}\right )$ where $D$ is the discriminant?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, it is.

Comment: You don't have the negative sign on $\frac{b}{2a}$

Comment: @StubbornAtom, corrected, thank you. BTW, was the solution helpful?

Comment: Yes, spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Making things geometrical the parabola should be above X-axis or touching it at one point ie having complex roots or is a perfect square. So $b^2-4ac\leq 0$ is a necessary condition.

Comment: Could you point out my mistake @Archis Welankar ?

Comment: See $b^2$ is always positive so one negative value in $a,C$ makes whole thing negative so that doesn't make sense hence I suppose the first condition is important. Note I am not that strong at calculus right now.