# Show that if $a > 0$, then $ax^2 + bx + c ≥ 0$ for all values of $x$ if and only if $b^2 − 4ac ≤ 0$.

Tags: proof-verification, quadratics

So I'm fairly new to proofs and was wondering how to solve this problem. This is my train of thought.

I listed the terms as so: $ax^2 + bx + c ≥ 0 ≥ b^2 − 4ac$.

From there I tried to complete the square and ended up with this:

$$x ≥ \sqrt{-c/a} ≥ \sqrt{(b^2/a) - 4ac - c/a}.$$

I'm not quite exactly sure how to show that if $a > 0$, then $ax^2 + bx + c ≥ 0$ for all values of $x$ if and only if $b^2 − 4ac ≤ 0$ and would greatly enjoy any help.

Thanks. Forgive my formatting.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. . If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Do you know what the discriminant of a quadratic is and what it tells you about the roots of the quadratic?

Comment: General advice for proofs: It's never good to start a proof by assuming or manipulating the result you're trying to obtain. In this case, your process has included $0 \ge b^2 - 4ac$ as its first step, but that's what you're trying to work towards (or from, in the "if" direction).

Comment: This has been answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1817348/321264

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$ax^2+bx+c=a\cdot\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}=a\cdot\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The roots of
$ax^2 + bx + c =0$
are
$\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$.

If the roots are complex,
then
$ax^2 + bx + c \ne 0$
for all real $x$.

If
$b^2-4ac < 0$,
the roots are complex.
If $a > 0$,
then
$ax^2+bx+c > 0$
for large enough $x$,
so
$ax^2+bx+c > 0$
for all $x$
since it has
no real roots.

If
$b^2-4ac = 0$,
the roots are real and equal.
The double root is
$\dfrac{-b}{2a}
$
so
$ax^2+bx+c
=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2
\ge 0$
for all $x$
and is zero only for
$x=\dfrac{-b}{2a}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $b^2-4ac<0$, there are not real x´s that satisfy

$ax^2+bx+c≥0$, in particular, the x's don't satisfy $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

So, what you are asking should be: Show that if $a>0$, then $ax^2+bx+c≥0$ if and only if $b^2-4ac≥0$.

**Proof**

⇒)Suppose $ax^2+bx+c≥0$. $$ax^2+bx+c = x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}$$

Then, completing the perfect square trinomial, we have:$$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}=(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=\frac{(2ax+b)^2+4ac-b^2}{4a^2}$$

So,  $$\frac{(2ax+b)^2+4ac-b^2}{4a^2}\geqslant0\Rightarrow(2ax+b)^2+4ac-b^2\geqslant0\Rightarrow(2ax+b)^2\geqslant b^2-4ac$$

Now, note that for the case when the equality holds$$(2ax+b)^2= b^2-4ac$$ since $$(2ax+b)^2⩾0$$ **because it´s a square**, implies that $$b^2-4ac⩾0$$  as desired.

⇐)Suppose $b^2-4ac⩾0$. With this fact, we´d like to show:$axì^2+bx+c≥0$. Aiming for a contradiction, let's suppose $$ax^2+bx+c<0$$. $$ax^2+bx+c<0\Rightarrow(2ax+b)^2+4ac-b^2<0\Rightarrow(2ax+b)^2<b^2-4ac$$Our hypothesis say:$$b^2-4ac⩾0$$When equality holds:$$b^2-4ac=0$$ We have:$$(2ax+b)^2<b^2-4ac\Rightarrow(2ax+b)^2<0$$ Wich is a contradiction since $$(2ax+b)^2⩾0$$ **because it´s a square**.Then $$ax^2+bx+c\ge0$$ as desired.

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability.

Comment: i've done it man. From now on, Will my answer appear if i google it?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Answer (score -2):

> 1.If the $b^2-4ac < 0$ then equation has no real root so graph of the $ax^2+bx+c$ will always be above $X-axis$.
>
> 2.If $b^2-4ac=0$ then equation will have only one real root.
>
> 3.If $ax^2+bx+c$ is Non negative then it has at most one real root so $b^2-4ac$ is nonpositive

so $ax^2+bx+c$ is always non negative iff $b^2-4ac$ is non positive

Comment: Please improve your answer by [formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) it.